# How to retrieve value from elements in array using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, arrays

I have multiple input fields like so:

```
<input type="text" name="card[]">
<input type="text" name="card[]">
<input type="text" name="card[]">
```

Users can add or remove these fields as required, therefore the name of the fields is an array. 
To get length of the array, this works fine:

```
var n = $("input[name^= 'card']").length;
```

How can I read value from the array?

I've tried this which didn't work:

```
var n = $("input[name^='card']").length;
var array = $("input[name^='card']");
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
 card_value=  array[i].val();
 alert(card_value);
}
```

This didn't work either:

```
var n = $("input[name^='card']").length;

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
 card_value=  $("input[name^='card["+i+"]']").val();
 alert(card_value);
}
```

How can I read value from this array?
Help!

Comment: Elaborate a little please, what value do you want to read, the value the user actually inputs within the `input`? And what do you want to retrieve, all of them?

Comment: try $(input.attr("[name^='card'])").length;

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should use:

```
card_value=  array.eq(i).val(); //gets jquery object at index i
```

or

```
card_value=  array[i].value; //gets dom element at index i
```

Comment: @scrappedcola how can i prevent same value ?

Comment: @FreddySidauruk what do you mean "prevent same value"? That's not related to the question I was answering. Generally one would use an if block to check value vs what's in array. if you have a question search the site for relevant questions and if you don't find one create your own question.

Answer (score 23):

Use map function

```
var values = $("input[name^='card']").map(function (idx, ele) {
   return $(ele).val();
}).get();
```

Comment: Hint: you can also use `$(this)` within the function and drop parameters idx and ele. And [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/#get2) is for extracting a real array from the jQuery object that gets returned by [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/).

Comment: thanks for @Robsch 's comment, the .get is important indeed, .map returned result is not a javascript array.

Answer (score 8):

`jQuery` collections have a built in iterator with `.each`:

```
$("input[name^='card']").each(function () {
   console.log($(this).val());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

to read an `array`, you can also utilize "`each`" method of `jQuery`:

```
$.each($("input[name^='card']"), function(index, val){
    console.log(index + " : " + val);
});
```

**bonus**: you can also read objects through this method.

[source](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

Answer (score 0):

Use: http://jsfiddle.net/xH79d/

```
var n = $("input[name^='card']").length;
var array = $("input[name^='card']");

for(i=0; i < n; i++) {

   // use .eq() within a jQuery object to navigate it by Index

   card_value = array.eq(i).attr('name'); // I'm assuming you wanted -name-
   // otherwise it'd be .eq(i).val(); (if you wanted the text value)
   alert(card_value);
}
```

​

Answer (score 0):

You can just loop though the items:

```
$("input[name^='card']").each(function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is incorrect.

`card_value = $(array[i]).val();` or `card_value = array[i].value;`

array[i] is not a jQuery object (for some reason).

Checking your browser's console can be helpful for things like this.