# Loop through array and show value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array with data inside (JavaScript/jQuery) that I'm wanting to loop through and print the value to the console. Now it seems pretty simple but I can't seem to get it to work at all. At the moment I only have one value but I don't think that will make a difference by adding more into it.

```
list = ["Example String"];

$j.each(list, function(item) {    
    console.info(item[0]); // Returns 0 in the console
    console.info(item); // Returns undefined in the console
});
```

Which I want to show in the console as;

```
Example String
Example String 2
Example String 3
```

*etc etc...*

[This is sort of on the right lines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12206685/7236046) but still not working - I tried `.eq`. I just think that because it doesn't have a key, using `[0]` is wrong in some way, perhaps? It must be quite obvious because I'm just not seeing why this isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the `each()` handler function the first parameter is the current index of the iteration. The *second* parameter is the value itself. Try this:

```js
var $j = $.noConflict();

list = ["Example String 1", "Example String 2", "Example String 3"];
$j.each(list, function(i, item) {
    console.info(item);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Also note that jQuery isn't really needed for a basic loop. You can use `for`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i+) {
  console.log(list[i]);
}
```

Or if you can use ECMA2015 features, `forEach()`, but note this is unsupported in < IE9:

```
list.forEach(function(item) {
  console.log(item);
});
```

Comment: @Cruiser yes indeed - I left that one out as the answer was getting long enough as it was :)

Comment: I'm using jQuery mainly because after I print to the console I want to do something else with the list on the page but thanks, that worked! I thought it'd be as simple as that, I just couldn't figure it out. Will accept the answer in 5m.

Comment: @dj_cd no problem, glad to help. Also note that you can still use jQuery within the standard `for` or `forEach` loops.

Answer (score 0):

Guess you want this:

```
$j.each(["string_1", "string_2", "string_3"], function(index, value) {
  console.log(value + " " + index);
});
```

What you are missing is, each takes 2 argument (index and value). So, when you use only **item** it indicates the index of array.

See [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) doc and examples here.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want for this?

```
var list = ["Example String"];
var $j = $.noConflict(); 
$j.each(list, function(index, item) {    
    console.info(item, index || "");
});
```