# How to retrieve value from elements in array using jQuery and use it to ajax data?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to follow this quesiton

[How to retrieve value from elements in array using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12206660/how-to-retrieve-value-from-elements-in-array-using-jquery)

like in my form. each table row has multiple inputs that are in the name attribute and it is an array.

```
<td><input type="number" name="quantity[]" class="form-control"></td>
<td><input type="number" name="unit[]" class="form-control"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="item_description[]" class="form-control"></td>
<td><input type="number" name="stock_no[]" class="form-control"></td>
<td><input type="number" name="eunitcost[]" class="form-control"></td>
```

and in my javascript code is this.

```
var counter = $("input[name^= 'quantity']").length;
        var array1 = $("input[name^= 'quantity']");
        var array2 = $("input[name^= 'unit']");
        var array3 = $("input[name^= 'item_description']");
        var array4 = $("input[name^= 'stock_no']");
        var array5 = $("input[name^= 'eunitcost']");
        var array6 = $("input[name^= 'ecost']");
        var i;
        for(i=0;i<counter;i++){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost/pm/admin/service/user-service.php',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    operation: 'pr-items',
                    pr_no: $('#prno').val(),
                    quantity: array1.eq(i).val(),
                    unit: array2.eq(i).val(),
                    item_description: array3.eq(i).val(),
                    stock_no: array4.eq(i).val(),
                    eunitcost: array5.eq(i).val(),
                    ecost: array6.eq(i).val

                },

                success: function(data) {
                    alert('pr items success');
                    //todo
                },
                error: function(data){
                    alert('pr items error');
                    //todo
                }
            });   
        }
```

what seems to be the problem why my arrays can't enter in ajax data?

Comment: The question is still a little unclear.  What have you done to test this out?  Are you receiving any values?  Tell us what you've done so far and prove it, so that we know how you came up with this question

Comment: ajax isnt working. It doesn't alert either from success or error

Comment: Have you checked your ajax call in the dev tools' Network tab?

Comment: I can't seem find my ajax call in XHR ?